# Scraping the data from google image search

Tags: python, search, web-scraping, google-image-search

I have a set pictures of some kind of products for which I need to find similar ones using google images. I believe google doesn't allow you easily to scrape the data from it.

- So, does it really not?
- How would I go about bypassing it? A combination of proxy + tor + maybe a headless browser?
- Is there a better image data source / search engine which I can use?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, [their robots.txt](http://images.google.com/robots.txt) disallows scraping from any crawler by this rule:

> ```
> User-agent: *
> Disallow: /search
> ```

However you might have some luck using the [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview).

Comment: I see there that you can use google search for your own website, but how I want to use my python script to search for image in google and I don't have a website. How can I do that?